Flutter Web PWA on iOS - Unable to Send Push Message Data to index.html from Service Worker
I'm working on a Flutter Web app that uses web push notifications. My setup works well on most platforms, but I'm experiencing issues on iOS when the PWA is added to the home screen.
Here's the code I use for the push event listener in my service worker:
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    console.log("Received push event:", event);

    if (event.data) {
        try {
            const data = event.data.json();
            handlePushMessage(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error parsing push message data:", error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error("No data in push event.");
    }
});


Inside the handlePushMessage function, I process the data, adjust the badge, and perform some extra work. I then attempt to send data to index.html and my Flutter app classes using channel.postMessage or clients.matchAll().
This approach works on most platforms, but on iOS when the app is installed as a PWA on the home screen, I encounter issues. The data does not get sent to index.html, and it seems like postMessage or clients isn't functioning as expected.
Confirmed the service worker is registered and active.
Used clients.matchAll() to get client instances to send messages to, but without success.
Tested different messaging approaches between the service worker and the main app.
Question
Why might channel.postMessage or clients.matchAll() be unable to send data from the service worker to index.html in a Flutter Web PWA on iOS? Is there an iOS-specific limitation or workaround for this issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
